# Why isn't wordnik's php api loading the required classes?

Tags: php, api, class

I'm getting the following error with wordnik's php api
**Fatal error: Class 'Example' not found in Swagger.php on line 212**

I've edited Swagger.php to get it to work, below is the original function

```
function swagger_autoloader($className) {
    $currentDir = substr(__FILE__, 0, strrpos(__FILE__, '/'));
    if (file_exists($currentDir . '/' . $className . '.php')) {
        include $currentDir . '/' . $className . '.php';
    } elseif (file_exists($currentDir . '/models/' . $className . '.php')) {
        include $currentDir . '/models/' . $className . '.php';
    }
}
```

The working code I changed to is

```
function swagger_autoloader($className) 
{
        include $currentDir . '/models/' . $className . '.php'; 
}
```

**MORE INFO**

My file structure is as follows.
WORDNIK (contains start.php)>>>WORDNIK (contains Swagger.php)>>MODELS (contains Example.php)

- I'm using wampserver 2.2 with php 5.4.3

**UPDATE/EDIT**

Using the following code

```
function swagger_autoloader($className) {
    echo "dirname(__FILE__)= ",dirname(__FILE__);
    $currentDir = substr(__FILE__, 0, strrpos(__FILE__, '/'));
    echo "currentDir=".$currentDir."</br>";
    echo "className=".$className."</br>";
    echo "__FILE__=",__FILE__."<br/>";
    die();
```

I get the results

- `dirname(__FILE__)=D:\wamp\www\wordnik\wordnik`
- currentDir=
- className=Example
- `__FILE__=D:\wamp\www\wordnik\wordnik\Swagger.php`

As suggested by vcampitelli, using either `__DIR__` or `dirname(__FILE__)` works.

**MY QUESTION**

Why doesn't the original function work?

**UNIMPORTANT INFO**

For people struggling through the examples, here is my start.php file

```
<?php
require('./wordnik/Swagger.php');
require('./wordnik/WordApi.php');
require('./wordnik/AccountApi.php');
require('./wordnik/WordsApi.php');
require('./wordnik/WordListApi.php');
require('./wordnik/WordListsApi.php');

$myAPIKey = 'replace_this_with_your_real_api';
$client = new APIClient($myAPIKey, 'http://api.wordnik.com/v4');

$wordApi = new WordApi($client);
$example = $wordApi->getTopExample('irony');
print $example->text;
?>
```

Comment: I can suppose that there is a file `Example.php` at the same location as `Swagger.php`. So your autoload function includes this file before `models/Example.php` and there is not Example class in it. Could it be like that?

Comment: You would think so, but no there isn't. The only files in that folder are AccountApi.php, Swagger.php, WordApi.php, WordListApi.php, WordListsApi.php and WordsApi.php

Comment: Lib author here. As vcampitelli said, the best way to debug is to echo values of __FILE__ and $currentDir. It's possible that wampserver isn't giving you the correct value for __FILE__ for some reason. We've seen issues with autoloading with PHP 5.2 but that's obviously not the case for you if you are on 5.4.x.

Comment: OK, I've updated my question. Sorry about the delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does `$currentDir` return? Have you tried using `__DIR__` or `dirname(__FILE__)` (they are the same) instead of that `substr`?

If you are using the second example just as you posted (without declaring `$currentDir`), so that is the problem at your original code: `$currentDir` is not returning the right folder!

With the original code, which file is being included? Because, actually, I think no one is! Use `echo` inside those `if` statements to check that!

Comment: Agree, can we see the values of `__FILE__` and $currentDir, as set by the original script? Feels like `__FILE__` must be off somehow.

Answer (score 1):

The original function doesn't work because it is looking for the position of a UNIX-style forward slash '/', whereas you are on Windows and have backslashes '\'. That's a bug! I'll fix the lib to use dirname(**FILE**) as you do. Thanks for pointing out the error.

Comment: Thanks for following it up :) Love wordnik!

Comment: Pushed the fix. https://github.com/wordnik/wordnik-php/commit/f4206965a882f94ce6b7336955bb9c38ac88c11b

Comment: You shouldn't need to require anything but Swagger.php -- before you were having to require WordApi.php etc because of this same bug.